# How to initialize the python engine in VB.net

Tags: python, .net, vb.net, python.net

I am trying to execute a simple Python script from VB.net using PythonNet.  When I use the following code I get the error "System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'Delegates' threw an exception.'" at the line of code showing "PythonEngine.Initialize()"  I have tried forward and reverse slashes and I have tried using "PythonEngine.Initialize(CType("C:/Users/realt/anaconda3/python310.dll", IEnumerable(Of String)))"  How can I get this to work?

```
Imports Python.Runtime


Public Class Form1    
     Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click


        Runtime.PythonDLL = "C:\Users\realt\anaconda3\python310.dll"
        PythonEngine.Initialize()
        Using Py.GIL()
            Dim np As Object = Py.Import("numpy")
            TextBox3.Text = ToString(np.cos(np.pi * 2))

        End Using

    End Sub
End Class
```

I am basically trying to convert the C# example shown at https://pypi.org/project/pythonnet/ to VB.net.

Comment: What is `Runtime` is it also `PythonEngine`? What if you try `PythonEngine.PythonDLL = "C:\Users\realt\anaconda3\python310.dll"`

Comment: Runtime is a class "Python.Runtime.Runtime"  It says it is used to access the Python C API.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Python.Runtime.PythonDLL = "C:\Users\realt\anaconda3\python310.dll"
        PythonEngine.Initialize()

        Using Py.GIL()
            Dim np As Object = Py.Import("numpy")
            TextBox3.Text = np.cos(np.pi * 2).ToString()
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Python.Runtime.PythonDLL gives the error 'PythonDLL is not a member of 'Python.Runtime'

Comment: Python.Runtime.Runtime.PythonDLL seems like it gets us one step closer but it throws the exception that it could not load "C:\Users\realt\anaconda3\python310.dll"